# nodejs passport callback not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am very new to both JS and NodeJs/Express. I am writing a proof of concept MVP node/express app that uses passport for authentication (via social logins).

I have written the server and installed all required packages and so far everything (apart from the authentication bit works).

Note: I have already set up my credentials at the various social media company's ends, so this is not the problem.

Here is a snippet of my code:

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
compression = require('compression'),
shouldCompress = (req, res) => {
    if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {
      // don't compress responses if this request header is present
      return false;
    }
    // fallback to standard compression
    return compression.filter(req, res);
  };

const app = express();

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Parsing related
app.use(express.urlencoded( { extended: false })); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(express.json()); //Used to parse JSON bodies

app.use(compression({
    filter:shouldCompress,
    threshold: 3
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.disable('x-powered-by');

// Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the session.
var passport = require('passport');
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/member', require('./routes/users'));


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}`));
```

### routes/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET authentication funcs */
let authentication = require('../controllers/auth.js');

router.get('/subscribe', (req, res) => { res.render('subscribe'); });
router.post('/subscribe', authentication.subscribe);

module.exports = router;
```

### controllers/auth.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const model = require("../models");

const passport = require('passport');

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user)
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {
    done(null, email)
})


function validateLead(req, done) {
    mail = req.body.lead_email;
    console.log('validateLead() called!');

    models.Lead.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    }).then(/* some logic */).catch();
        } else {
            // email already taken ..
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'This email address is already subscribed'
            });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred!', err);
    });
}

exports.subscribe = function(req, res, next) {
    switch (req.body.source) {
        case 'facebook':
            passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
                    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                    callbackURL: process.env.FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL
                },
                function(accessToken, refreshToken, fbProfile, done) {
                    console.log('FB callback!');
                    profile = {
                        'email': fbProfile.email,
                        'firstName': '',
                        'LastName': '',
                        'leadSource': '',
                        'tags': [],
                    };
                    return validateLead(req, done, profile);
                }
            ));
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown');
      }
}
```

### views/test.eps

```
<a href='#'><i id='facebook' class='foobar'></i></a>
```

### (simplified) views/layout.eps

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('i.foobar').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "/member/subscribe",
          data: {
            "source": $(this).attr('id')
          },
          dataType: "json",
          timeout: 5000 // 5000ms
        }).done(function(data) {
          // is called if request is successful
          console.log(data.fridge);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
          // is called if request fails or timeout is reached
          alert('Request could not complete: ' + status);
        });
      });
    });
```

I have put `console.log()` messages in controllers/auth.js and I can see that the FB code branch is being reached. However, when log messages in `validateLead()` and the FB callback function are not being reached.

What is the cause of this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you put this into a codesandbox ? It would be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things I can see :

As far as I could see you didn't configure passportjs. You need to have a configuration file, which for you would be the `controllers/auth.js`. To configure passport you need to run `require('./controllers/auth')(passport);` in `app.js`.

For passport to be able to ingest that config you need to export them as a function that takes passport e.g. `module.exports = passport => {passport.use('facebook')}`

Your config file (in `exports.subscribe`) is not a format that passport will understand. Follow the Documentation on how to create that config file.

---

Passport provides you with authentication *middleware*, I am pretty sure that you cannot create "wrappers" for them like in `controllers/auth.js`. To access passport's auth functions you use `passport.authenticate('facebook', callback())(req, res, next)` in `routes/users.js`.

Passport only provides middleware to serialize and deserialize users.

---

Your deserialization is not yet set up. You need a call to the db to fetch the user from session store.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good starting point. However, when I try to configure passport in the way you suggest, I get the following error: `TypeError: require(...) is not a function`

Comment: Nodejs should have require() available ... I would need to see your entire app in action to help you with that error.